# How to get the selected check boxes in Kendo Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm new to kendo I have a list populated from a data source (with template : Each list item has mobile switch in it).I need to get all the id's of selected mobile switches when I clicked on a single button. Can anyone let me know how to do that in kendo ?

Cheers,

Chinthaka

Comment: Is the value of the switch bound to a property on the data items in the DataSource?

Comment: Yes even the I'd from table

Answer (score 0):

Without the code it is hard to give an exact answer, but you should be able to just loop over the data items in the array and find the ones that are selected.

For example:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource( ... );

function getSelected() {
    return $.grep(dataSource.view(), function (item) {
        return item.selected;
    });
}
```

Assuming the switches/checkboxes are bound to the "selected" property.

---

In response to your comment, you can get the selected checkbox element IDs with jQuery:

```
 $("#workcenters :checkbox:checked").map(function (index, checkbox) {
    return $(checkbox).attr("id");
});
```

Comment: Is there any way for me do do it in jquerry without using the data source

Comment: Here is my code:<ul id="workcenters">
          
        </ul>  Template being bind to this so I'm trying to access all the checked boxes   $('#workcenters :checkbox:checked').attr('id') but I'm getting only one checked  value

Answer (score 0):

I solved that Using following code (Only Active Items checked items)

```
var checkedWorkCentersIds = new Array();
$('#workcenters :checkbox:checked').map(function () {
  if (this.checked == true) {
    checkedWorkCentersIds.push(this.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: `.map()` returns an array of new items. You don't need to push the items into the array manually. Your jQuery selector alreayd grabs only the checked ones, so your `if` statement is also not needed. This would work: `var checkedWorkCentersIds = $('#workcenters :checkbox:checked').map(function () { return this.id; });`